# Cannot use perimetric complexity function in Mathematica

Tags: image-processing, image

I am very new to Mathematica, so I'm having difficulties troubleshooting the code that I am trying to resolve (I'm much more familiar with R, but sadly I haven't found a package to do this). In any case, the function comes from Page 26 of [this paper](https://content.wolfram.com/uploads/sites/19/2012/02/Watson.pdf), which already took forever to copy and fix the code from the pdf. I believe the first portion is just documentation for the function and can probably be ignored given how long it is:

```
PerimetricComplexity::usage = 
  "PerimetricComplexity[image_,opts___Rule] Compute the perimetric \
complexity of a binary image. Perimetric complexity is defined as the \
square of the sum of inner and outer perimeters divided by the \
foreground area, divided by 4*pi. By default, foreground pixels are \
white (1). The function returns a list: {perimeter, area, \
complexity}. Optionally, the image can be filtered and thresholded \
before calculation of complexity, to provide a a better estimate of \
the visual complexity of the image. Options available are Pad (width \
of padding to add around image), Magnification (factor by which to \
magnify each pixel before calulation of complexity), Method \
(\"PerimeterLength\" or \"PolygonalLength\", the method used to \
compute the perimeter), Threshold (a numerical threshold, or the \
method to use in thresholding operations after filtering), and Filter \
(None: no filter, \"Gaussian\" for Gaussian filter; \"Sech\" for a \
Hyperbolic Secant filter; or an array supplied directly as the filter \
kernel. For the gaussian and the Sech, the size of the filter is \
determined by the ViewingDistance option), ViewingDistance (in \
pixels, used to determine the radius of Gaussian and Sech filters), \
MorphologicalOperators (whether to use Mathematica's built in \
operators), Normalized (whether to normalize complexity by the value \
for a disk, 4*pi). Defaults are: {{Magnification -> Automatic, Pad -> \
Automatic, Verbose -> False, Threshold -> 0.5, Method -> \
\"PolygonalLength\", Filter -> \"Sech\", Normalized -> True, \
ViewingDistance -> 48/ArcTan[1°], MorphologicalOperators -> True}, \
SechScale -> 2.16/60, GaussianScale -> 2.33/60, ReturnImages -> \
False}";

Options[PerimetricComplexity] = {Magnification -> Automatic, 
   Pad -> Automatic, Verbose -> False, Threshold -> 0.5, 
   Method -> "PolygonalLength", Filter Ø -> "Sech", 
   Normalized -> True, ViewingDistance -> 48 / ArcTan[1. °], 
   MorphologicalOperators -> True, SechScale -> 2.16 / 60, 
   GaussianScale -> 2.33 / 60, ReturnImages -> False};

PerimetricComplexity[image_, opts___Rule] := 
 Module[{tmp, tmp0, tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, tmp4, tmp5, plength, area, mag, 
   radius, pad, verbose, fdim, pc, norm, threshold, method, filter, 
   vdist, pixelsperdegree, sechpixels, sechdegrees, morpho, sechscale,
    gscale, anglescale, rimages, images},
  {mag, pad, verbose, threshold, method, filter, norm, vdist, morpho, 
    sechscale, gscale, 
    rimages} = {Magnification, Pad, Verbose, Threshold, Method, 
      Filter, Normalized, ViewingDistance, MorphologicalOperators, 
      SechScale, GaussianScale, ReturnImages} /. {opts} /. 
    Options[PerimetricComplexity]; anglescale = ArcTan[1. Degree]; 
  If[mag === Automatic, mag = Switch[filter
     , None, 1
     , _?ListQ, 1
     , "Gaussian", Ceiling[2. / (vdist anglescale gscale)]
     , "Sech", Ceiling[3. / (vdist anglescale sechscale)]
     ]];
  pixelsperdegree = mag vdist anglescale; 
  sechpixels = Ceiling[pixelsperdegree 3 sechscale]; 
  If[pad === Automatic,
   pad = If[filter === None, 2,
     Ceiling[pixelsperdegree sechscale]]]; 
  If[EvenQ[sechpixels], sechpixels++]; 
  sechdegrees = sechpixels / pixelsperdegree; 
  radius = 2 gscale pixelsperdegree / Sqrt[2 Pi]; 
  tmp0 = Binarize[image]; 
  tmp1 = If[mag > 1, ImageResize[tmp0, mag ImageDimensions[tmp0]],
    tmp0];
  tmp2 = ImagePad[tmp1, pad]; tmp4 = Switch[filter
    , None, tmp2
    , _?ListQ, ImageConvolve[tmp2, filter]
    , "Gaussian", GaussianFilter[tmp2, radius]
    , "Sech"
    , ImageConvolve[tmp2, SechKernel2D[sechpixels {1, 1},
      sechdegrees {1, 1}, sechscale]]
    ];
  
  tmp5 = If[ImageType[tmp4] === "Bit", tmp4,
    If[NumericQ[threshold], Binarize[tmp4, threshold],
     Binarize[tmp4, Method -> threshold]]];
  
  {plength, area} = If[morpho,
    Total[
     Last /@ 
      (tst = ComponentMeasurements[MorphologicalComponents[tmp5],
         {method, "Count"}, CornerNeighbors -> False])]
    ,
    {PerimeterLength[tmp5, Switch[method, "PerimeterLength",
       PixelBorderLength, "PolygonalLength", PixelPathLength]],
     Total[ImageData[tmp5], 2]}];
  (*Print["mag = ",mag," ppd = ",pixelsperdegree,
  "sechpixels = ",sechpixels," pad = ",pad];*)
  tmp6 = MorphologicalPerimeter[tmp5, CornerNeighbors -> False]; 
  images = {tmp2, tmp4, tmp5, ColorCombine[{tmp2, tmp6, tmp6}]}; 
  If[verbose, (
    Print @ GraphicsRow[images, ImageSize -> 400];
    )];
  {plength, area, (plength^2 / area) / If[norm, 4 Pi, 1]} // 
   If[rimages, Append[#, images], #] &
   ]
```

When I run the programmed function into Mathematica like so (I use a screenshot here because I want it to be clear that I have used an image):

[image]

I get this very long error (which I use a screenshot again because the error isn't easy to copy and paste here):

[image]

The last part of the "output" seems to give this really funky approximation that the function was supposed to achieve:

```
{plength$23621, area$23621, (0.0795775 plength$23621^2)/area$23621}
```

I previously tried to get help with this on Stack Overflow, but it seemed difficult to find somebody who could help. I've tried copy and pasting the image and directly inserting it but neither worked. I believe this function was designed for Version 8 of Mathematica. I am currently using Version 13.2 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: From [this](https://www.mathematica-journal.com/2012/02/17/perimetric-complexity-of-binary-digital-images/) link you can download the notebook using the nb link to the right of the title. Try that to eliminate PDF to code transcription errors.

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine. Evaluate all the cells in the Appendix and note that `Image` must be `Binarize`'d if it is not already.

Comment: Wow, that's great! That worked like a charm. Feel free to leave an answer and I will accept it since you solved this riddle for me. I imagine this will be very helpful for somebody who has to use this function in the future (indeed I had trouble finding any other resources for using this myself).

Comment: 不客气, you may be interested in [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2509775) post on the Wolfram Community site.

Comment: Oh wow, that is also interesting. 謝謝！